# Jquery hasClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to check if one of the DIV's has class "visible" which is being add by a jquery plugin, it seems not to work.

it works when i check the first element, but if i want to check next div, it doenst finds it.

help is appreciated.

My DIV

```
<div class="swiper-slide welcome" id="welcome"></div>
```

2nd DIV

```
<div class="swiper-slide intro-early-life" id="intro-early-life"></div>
```

MY JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.welcome').hasClass('swiper-slide-visible')) {
        alert("working");
    }
});
</script>
```

Im not using same ID, maybe it was my bad explanation. I can use the class as well, no difference.

Comment: Which second element??? FYI, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178)

Comment: Which JQuery version are you using?

Comment: im using the latest version, google API

Comment: Again, which second element are you talking about? Do you mean second class on same element instead?

Comment: i mean the next DIV, this is a full page slideshow, when i move to next slide i want jquery to check, the slideshow itself is using jquery also.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#welcome').hasClass('swiper-slide') &&  $('#welcome').hasClass('visible')) {
        alert("working");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#welcome').is(":visible") && $('#welcome').hasClass("swiper-slide")) {
    alert("Yeah!");
}
```

Perhaps that would work better?

Edit: Also `swiper-slide-visible` class doesn't exist on the page - perhaps this is the issue...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use also as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#welcome').hasClasses(['swiper-slide', 'visible']);) {
        alert("working");
    }
});

$.fn.extend({
    hasClasses: function (selectors) {
        var self = this;
        for (var i in selectors) {
            if ($(self).hasClass(selectors[i])) 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if ($('#welcome').is('.swiper-slide, .visible'){
```

---

`Id` Must Be unique you can use `classes` instaed

[Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.is()` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.welcome').is('.swiper-slide.visible')) {
        alert("working");
    }
});
```